# Sending a binary file in Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

In a certain `GET` request, I need to read a file locally, depending on parameters in the request, and send it on request's input stream. How do I do it?

```
class GetArchives(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, param1, param2):
        path = calculate_path(param1, param2)
        try:
            f = open(path, 'rb')
            # TODO: send this file to request's input stream.
        except IOError:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404, 'Invalid archive')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this(not for big file):

```
try:
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        self.write(data)
    self.finish()
```

There is `StaticFileHandler` in tornado, see [tornado doc](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L1630)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You say this is not to be used for big files. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: The files I will be dealing with will be at most 50 MB in size.

Comment: @missingfaktor: It reads the whole file in at once, which will increase memory usage substantially.

Comment: @nneonneo, okay, thank you. What'll be a good alternative way?

Comment: `StaticFileHandler` is certainly nice; the alternative is to just read and write chunks at a time. If you like I can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a solution that works for arbitrary-sized files:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    while 1:
        data = f.read(16384) # or some other nice-sized chunk
        if not data: break
        self.write(data)
self.finish()
```